# Delphi firemonkey listboxitem with accessory - how to detect click on it?

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey

I have a listbox with various items. Some have an accessory attached (more and details).

I cannot find a way to detect when the accessory is clicked and not the listbox item itself. I need to distinguish between clicks on the listboxitem and clicks on its accessory, or is this not supported at all?

Comment: I think that you need to give us (at least me) a concrete example to understand your issue.

Comment: @Dsm, [a picture is worth a thousand words](https://i.imgur.com/PwwHd0I.png) :) Softtouch, it can be implemented, just, do you want to keep functionality as it is and only detect click inside the accessory control area? I mean, do you want to keep the item the accessory belongs to being selected? Or you want that object behave as it was separated from the item (if you click its area, it won't select the item)?

Comment: I need the object to behave like its separated from the item, so user can click the listboxitem to do things, and can also click the accessory to do other things.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is when creating the ITEM give create a Procedure and assign it to the (OnClick) event :

```
var
BtnDelete : Tspeedbutton;      
begin
      BtnDelete := TSpeedbutton.Create(self);
      btndelete.Align := TAlignlayout(3);
      btndelete.OnClick := ProcDeleteRDV;
      Btndelete.StyleLookup := 'cleareditbutton';
      BtnDelete.Name :='RDV'+ vartostr(FieldValues['Num_rdv']);
      TlistBoxItem.AddObject(BtnDelete);
end;
```

and on the assigned Procedure i retrieve the button name  which in my case contain a primary key that i'm gonna use when i want to delete data:

```
var
 clickedbuttonname : string;
begin
 clickedbuttonname := TSpeedbutton(sender).Name;
 { Your other code here}
end;
```

Hope this will help you .